# Open implementation of IP SLA

Tags: monitoring, cisco

Is there a possibility to use a Linux server as an Cisco IP SLA probe? Is there any open implementation of IP SLA available which is compatible with Cisco responders?

Answer (score 1):

No, IP SLA is cisco only.  You would have to look into other technologies if you want a cross platform solution.